# jquery restrict only < and > symbol in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
$j("#<%= txtGradingScale.ClientID%>").bind("keypress", function (e) 
{
    var keyed = $j(this).val();
   $j("#<%= txtGradingScale.ClientID%>").html
     (keyed.replace(/\<>/gi,   ''));

  });
```

Have to restrict greter than and lesser than symbol in textbox while entering .

above code is not working pls suggest the method .i tried keyCode and Charcode but it's not working

Comment: Thanks ..should follow it

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because the regular expression `/\<>/` (the escape character `\` is not needed) is looking for `<>` and not the characters by themselves, what you want to do is:

```
$('textarea[name="test"]').keyup(function(e) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[<>]/ig, ''));
});
```

This will match any instance of the `<` and `>` characters no matter what order they appear in.

You should also use `keyup` instead of `keypress` because `keypress` will only trigger after the next key gets hit, while `keyup` will trigger whenever the key is released.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0L9a89y/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to test using `e.which` and compare with corresponding codes for `<` and `>`. If you `return false` or invoke `e.preventDefault()` when they are encountered, that should do it.

```js
$('#myText').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if( e.which === 60 || e.which === 62 ) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="myText" id="myText"/>
```